# How to get the graph definition for tensorflow's pre-made estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

As a beginner to tensorflow, I am curious to see the graph defined by tensorflow's pre-made estimator (for example, `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`).

Having the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(    
    feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x")],
    model_dir="stackoverflow_model"
)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": np.arange(5)}, y=np.array([1] * 5), shuffle=True)

estimator.train(input_fn)
```

I can see the graph defined by `LinearClassifier` perfectly on tensorboard:

[image]

However, when I get "nothing" if I do:

```
print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

I only get:

```
versions {
  producer: 26
}
```

So my question is: where is the graph defined by `LinearClassifier` and how do I properly inspect it `using as_graph_def()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Using TensorFlow v1.8.0 gets the complete graph definition printed.

Comment: @J.E.K can you elaborate?

Comment: Your code works fine using TF v1.8.0. The complete graph definition gets printed as expected. Inspecting the pre-defined graph of `LinearClassifer` using `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` should work. Which version of TensorFlow do you use?

Comment: I am using v 1.8.0. Have you tried actually running my code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried your code (copy and paste).

Comment: I meet the same issues. And I am using tf 1.12. Did you solve this problem?